# Does Intellij Idea 8.1.x install and run on Mac OSX 10.6?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, intellij-idea

Does Intellij Idea 8.1.x install and run on Mac OSX 10.6 (snow-leopard)?

Are there any special steps needed to get it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we've verified that it works fine on the Snow Leopard. The new version of Java 1.6 fixes the known problems with menus and crashes which affected IDEA on the previous version after Java Update 4 (promised to be fixed in Java Update 5).

There is no JDK 1.5 on Snow Leopard, so IDEA will use JDK 1.6 despite of the settings in the Info.plist file.

If you'll have any problems, it's recommended to replace the Java application stub with the new version:

overwrite **/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea** with
**/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub**.

The new application stub will be bundled with the next IDEA builds. Note that with the old stub IDEA will run under 32-bit JVM, while with the new stub it will run under 64-bit JVM.